# not enforcing "Users in this role cannot access opportunities that they do not own that are associated with accounts that they do own"

Tags: permissions, system-permissions

I have this setting:
Role ID Sales opportunity access: Users in this role can edit all opportunities associated with accounts that they own, regardless of who owns the opportunities

OWD: Opportunity Public Read Only
object setting on Sales Ops Profile : Read, Create, Edit

I login as Wilsen (profile: Sales Ops and Role ID Sales)
i have account owner by wilsen, and under account there is opportunity with owner 'Self-serve',
i want to change the opportunity owner to myself (wilsen). But i get error You don’t have permission to take that action on this record or related records. For help, contact your Salesforce admin.

do you know what did i missed?

Answer (score 2):

There are four levels of access a user can have on a record. In increasing order of access, they are read, edit, transfer†, and full/owner. To change ownership, the user must have transfer or full access. The edit access level isn't as powerful as the higher levels. Transfer is the minimum access level required to change ownership for a record not owned by the user or one of the user's subordinates lower in the hierarchy. If the owner and user are in the same role, they can't take ownership of each other's records. This setting is meant to be used to allow an account owner to make changes to opportunities, cases, and contacts for that account.

†This permission isn't available on most objects.

Comment: for my cases i want to change opportunity owner with different roles, 'Self-serve' is under CEO role which is its above of ID Sales Role that Wilsen Had.
And if i add transfer record on Sales Ops Profile, it will make the profile can edit every object owner right? i just want the account owner can edit owner of opportunity under their account.

Comment: @MustikaFarma there's no out of the box solution for this that I recall.  Most organizations create custom code to handle this.

Comment: aaah i see. cmiiw, so the role permission "Users in this role can edit all opportunities associated with accounts that they own, regardless of who owns the opportunities" is only give the access to edit the record, but not edit the ownership. if i want to have the access to change the ownership i should give access transfer record (but this impact to all object, not only opportunity under account). 
so, for this cases there is no standar setting permission that i can do, if i still want it i should make a custome code to handle it.